# Angular SSR Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory

Tags: angular, cpanel, server-side-rendering

I have deployed angular ssr project to cpanel and i'm getting error when running the project using this command,
`node dist/angular-universal/server/main.js`.

Error:

```
Node Express server listening on http://localhost:4000
Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "/home/angularssrtest/public_html/dist/browser"
    at Function.render (/home/angularssrtest/public_html/dist/angular-universal/server/main.js:1:440409)
    at ServerResponse.render (/home/angularssrtest/public_html/dist/angular-universal/server/main.js:1:891199)
    at server.get (/home/angularssrtest/public_html/dist/angular-universal/server/main.js:1:2976541)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/angularssrtest/public_html/dist/angular-universal/server/main.js:1:464045)
    at next (/home/angularssrtest/public_html/dist/angular-universal/server/main.js:1:448841)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/angularssrtest/public_html/dist/angular-universal/server/main.js:1:448870)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/angularssrtest/public_html/dist/angular-universal/server/main.js:1:464045)
    at /home/angularssrtest/public_html/dist/angular-universal/server/main.js:1:3290536
    at param (/home/angularssrtest/public_html/dist/angular-universal/server/main.js:1:3292042)
    at param (/home/angularssrtest/public_html/dist/angular-universal/server/main.js:1:3292449)
```

This is my folder structure.

public_html:

- dist:

  - angular-universal

    - browser
    - server
      .htaccess

---

.htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
# Redirect Public ports to NodeJS port
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:4000/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:4000/$1 [P,L]
</IfModule>
```

reference: https://www.purcellyoon.com/insights/articles/angular-universal-server-side-rendering-ssr-with-cpanel-whm

Please help to fix the issue.

Thanks Advanced.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problems following the same reference:  https://www.purcellyoon.com/insights/articles/angular-universal-server-side-rendering-ssr-with-cpanel-whm

Here is how i fixed the issue:
Upload the `dist` folder. In most cases your dist folder have your project name as folder in it. If this is your case, after upload to cPanel, the directory should look like this `dist/PROJECT_NAME/server` and `dist/PROJECT_NAME/browser` inside your public_html

Then login to your server via ssh and run these commands:
`cd public_html` -> it should look like `/home/account_name/public_html node dist/PROJECT_NAME/server/main.js`
output should be: `Node Express server listening on http://localhost:4000` then access the site url and your site should load fine.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed mine by changing the line about 'distFolder':
From

`const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), "dist/browser");`

to

`const distFolder = join(__dirname, "../../dist/browser");`

`__dirname` seems a better way to dynamically get the folder name.